# Missing template for this request but it exists?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, templates

> "PagesController#home is missing a template for request formats: text/html"
> NOTE!
> Unless told otherwise, Rails expects an action to render a template with the same name,
> contained in a folder named after its controller. If this controller is an API responding with 204 (No Content),
> which does not require a template, then this error will occur when trying to access it via browser,
> since we expect an HTML template to be rendered for such requests. If that's the case, carry on.

However, I have the home.html.erb file:

[image]

pages_controller.rb

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
  end

  def about
  end
end
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get "home", to: "pages#home", as: "home"
  get "about", to: "pages#about", as: "about"

  root "pages#home"
end
```

What could the problem be?

Comment: There is nothing notably wrong based on what is posted here. Are you certain this is identical to your actual code?

Answer (score 0):

Did you restart the server after adding the routes in `config/routes.rb`?
You need to restart the server after making any changes in the `config` directory.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/30974908)

Comment: @radrow: It looks like an answer to me. Admittedly, it's a pretty standard troubleshooting technique that we'd like to think most Stack Overflow users will have tried before posting a question. But it's also something that's easy to overlook, and especially if the need to restart the server isn't well established.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling it explicitly? If that's not working, make sure to reboot everything and try again

```rb
def home
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render :home }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Powershell or the Command Prompt to run Rails Server? I was having this exact issue when I was using Powershell for rails server but if I ran rails server using the command prompt the exact same code worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

This answer may be specific to environment (Windows), but I had this issue with the Ruby on Rails "Hello, Rails!" guide (the template file existed in the correct path, but the error message indicated it did not). In my case, starting the server in `cmd` instead of `PowerShell` pointed me to a permission error, and running `cmd` as Administrator before starting the server fixed the error.

Oddly, trying to run `cmd` from VS Code to start the server gave me the same error as `PowerShell`, which was strange behavior. Running a separate instance of `cmd` did the trick.